# When should I call "useRef" in BottomSheet so it won't be null?

Tags: javascript, react-native, bottom-sheet, use-ref

I want a [BottomSheet](https://github.com/osdnk/react-native-reanimated-bottom-sheet) to appear (`sheetRef.current.snapTo(0)`) when a code bar is scanned. Does `sheetRef` stays at null because on scan, the BottomSheet doesn't exist in  DOM yet? How could it be corrected?

Simplified version of code:

```
const ScanScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const width = Dimensions.get("window").width;
  const height = Dimensions.get("window").height;

  const productModal = () => (
    <View style={{height: 450}}>
      <Text>Product: {product.name}. Swipe down to close.</Text>
    </View>
  );

  const sheetRef = useRef(null);

  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({ name: "" });

  const handleScannedCodeBar = async ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);

    if (data) { 
      setProduct({ name: "Mon produit scanné" });
      sheetRef?.current?.snapTo(0);
    } 
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleScannedCodeBar}
        style={{ height: height, width: width }}
      />
      {scanned && (
        <SafeAreaView>
          <BottomSheet
            ref={sheetRef}
            index={-1} //bottom sheet closed
            snapPoints={[450, 300, 0]}
            borderRadius={10}
            renderContent={productModal}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default ScanScreen;
```

I tried to trigger it with product and scanned states. It still returns `null` and doesn't scan anymore.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    sheetRef?.current?.snapTo(0);
 }, [product]);
```

With scanned condition, still returns `null`.

`if (scanned) sheetRef?.current?.snapTo(0);`

Answer (score 1):

Because BottomSheet only appears when scanned is true, you need to add `scanned` to your useEffect dependency:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    if(scanned)
      sheetRef?.current?.snapTo(0);
    else 
      sheetRef.current?.snapTo(2)
  },[scanned,product])
```

Im not sure what version of `BottomSheet` you are using, but the latest version have the `initialSnap` prop instead of `index`. So instead of -1 it should be set to 2 (the snap point index that is 0)

Comment: Removing the SafeAreaView is also necessary